# Does Foxy Cart Support payment to multiple recipients in a single transaction?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, masspay, foxycart

I have a shopping website.
For example user 1 registered in my website uploads a digital item for $10 and User 2 buys this product.  Now 18% of $10 goes to the admin and the rest goes to user 1.  So here payment goes to two people at same time; one is admin and second is user 1.
So does Foxy Cart support payment to multiple recipients in one transaction and if not then is there another way to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2013-11-11, FoxyCart doesn't, though it is on the radar (and you can accomplish something like this using an affiliate program, which may get you all or part of the way there).

To accomplish something similar you'd need to look into something like Stripe, PayPal Adaptive Payments, BalancedPayments, or WePay.